# Get WooCommerce products with similar SKU

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

As a result of my research, I can bring similar sku ones no matter which product I enter, but I encountered a problem, the sku code of the product I entered changes.

E.g:

1- ) 36.214.03

2- ) 36.214.19

3- ) 36.214.17

This is how sku values similar to the product I entered are returned. I keep the sku code of each product at the bottom. The Sku code of the product I entered should be "36,214,19" but it always prints the last Sku code as "36,214,17", how can I avoid this?

In short, what can I do so that the product's own sku code does not change?

[image: I am sharing an example picture]

Following my code: `functions.php`

```
function wc_get_product_skus( $sku_excerpt ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Get all product Ids and skus (standard objects) from a sku excerpt
    return $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT p.ID as id, pm.meta_value as sku
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta pm
            ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_sku'
        AND pm.meta_value LIKE '%s'
    ", '%'.$sku_excerpt.'%' ) );
}
```

`single-product.php`

```
$results = wc_get_product_skus('36.214.');

// Loop through results
foreach ( $results as $result ) {
    $product_id  = $result->id;
    $product_sku = $result->sku;

    // Get the WC_Product Object (if needed)
    $product     = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    // Testing output
    echo 'Sku : '.$product_sku.'<br>'; 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know WooCommerce well, but I don't understand what you're saying the problem is. Are you saying that after you run that code the SKU code for the current page's product comes back wrong through the WooCommerce API? I don't see the code to print the current SKU in your snippet, and it looks like your "Testing output" line is closer to the 1-) 2-) 3-) than the "Sku code" in your picture.

Comment: Is the order in which SKUs are returned the problem? If so add `ORDER BY pm.meta_value ASC` at the end of your query and the SKU ending with 19 will be returned last.

Comment: @rupi As an example, I took 1-2-3 screenshots, it's not that important. Actually I have a product and I have a sku code, I bring similar sku codes to that product. When I get similar sku, latest sku code crushes my product's sku

Comment: @Greg36 unfortunately this is not a solution, because the sku code of the product I entered can be in between.

Comment: And you're printing the SKU that's getting crushed using WC() or $product->get_sku()? In that case I guess the wc_get_product() is overwriting the current product saved in $product, but I'm surprised if it does that.

Comment: I did not touch the sku code part in the meta.php section, it is very interesting that the last of the sku codes returned with the foreach overwhelms the sku code of my product.

Comment: I found the place that squashed my sku code: $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
If I do this all my sku codes get the same value.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that'll be overwriting the $product global if you have that in scope. Save it in a different variable, something other than $product.

Comment: I did what you said and it worked, thank you very much.